# SOAP Client php api call, empty

Tags: php, soap-client

Trying to retrieve data based on a SOAP client call in php. It must be the "returnproperties" I haven't understood how to structure since it returns nothing. Any thoughts from the pros much appreciated.

SOAP Sample request from the API

```
POST /CRM/Company/V001/CompanyService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: api.test.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetCompanies xmlns="http://test.com/webservices">
      <searchParams>
        <ExternalId>string</ExternalId>
        <CompanyId>int</CompanyId>
        <CompanyIds>
          <int>int</int>
          <int>int</int>
        </CompanyIds>
        <CompanyName>string</CompanyName>
        <ChangedAfter>dateTime</ChangedAfter>
        <CompanyEmail>string</CompanyEmail>
        <CompanyPhone>string</CompanyPhone>
        <OrganizationNumber>string</OrganizationNumber>
      </searchParams>
      <returnProperties>
        <string>string</string>
        <string>string</string>
      </returnProperties>
    </GetCompanies>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

My php:

```
  $inputs = array(
        'searchParams' =>  array(
            "CompanyId" => "GUID"
        ), 'returnProperties' => array(
            "CompanyId"
        )
      );

 $CompanyService = new SoapClient ( "https://api.test.com/CRM/Company/V001/CompanyService.asmx?wsdl", $options );
$CompanyResult = $CompanyService->GetCompanies($inputs);
print_r($CompanyResult);
```